# Replace first occurrence of '.' in sql String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say we saved inside a `table` the following values on `Column` as `String`:

```
 Select ValuesT from TableT; 

  ValuesT
-9.827.08
-9.657.40
-80.000.00
-8.700.00
-8.542.43
-8.403.00
```

How could be replaced with nothing only the first occurrence of '.' (dot) from the string?

Ex: for `-9.827.08` should be `-9827.08`

I tried with `stuff` function but this won't work for `-80.000.00`

```
 select stuff( ValuesT ,3,1,'') from TableT
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `STUFF` function

Find the first occurance of `.` using `CHARINDEX` and remove it using `STUFF`

```
SELECT STUFF(valuesT, CHARINDEX('.', valuesT), 1, '')
FROM TableT
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

```
WITH sampleData AS
( 
  SELECT val FROM (VALUES 
  ('-9.827.08'), ('-9.657.40'), ('-80.000.00'), ('-8.700.00'),
  ('-8.542.43'),('-8.403.00')) x(val)
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(val, 1, d1.d-1)+SUBSTRING(val, d1.d+1, 100)
FROM sampleData
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX('.',val))) d1(d);
```

Its a little more code but just as efficient. There's a lot more you can do with this technique.

Comment: Nice! What is the scope of VALUES inside your CTE ?  I also tried something with CTE but I didn't come up with the result. 10x

Comment: The CTE was just a quick way to emulate a real table. No different than if I did this:

    CREATE table dbo.sampledata(val varchar(20));
    
    INSERT dbo.sampledata
    VALUES ('-9.827.08'), ('-9.657.40'), ('-80.000.00'), ('-8.700.00'),
           ('-8.542.43'),('-8.403.00');
    
    SELECT SUBSTRING(val, 1, d1.d-1)+SUBSTRING(val, d1.d+1, 100)
    FROM dbo.sampleData
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX('.',val))) d1(d);

edit: just now learned that you can't do SQL code in these replies ;)

Comment: Thanks! I just copied the code in SQL Environment and formated there.